# the relationship between $f(x)$ and $dx$ in $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, infinitesimals

In this example,

> If we use the relation $F'(x) = f(x)$, this consequence of the fundamental theorem may be written in the form
>
> $$ f(b) - f(a) = \int_a^b F'(x) dx = \color{#c66}{\boxed{\color{black}{ \int_a^b \frac{dF(x)}{\color{red}{dx}}\color{red}{dx} = \int_a^b dF(x)}}}, $$

In the last equation of this example, obviously, the two $dx$ are canceled in the left before we get the right, this indicates  that the relationship between $f(x)$ and $dx$ within $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is multiplication , but I cannot find a reasonable explanation for this.
Using infinitely small quantities to explain it is wrong since  [infinitely small has no place in modern mathematics saying here](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=_kYBqLc5QoQC&pg=PA404&lpg=PA404&dq=is%20replaced%20by%20the%20infinitely%20small%20quantity&source=bl&ots=qPT0BODYtK&sig=JdspseUMZCWouacpWgSpPtsJ0IU&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia8LTAzKbMAhVBQpQKHRjSDTkQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=is%20replaced%20by%20the%20infinitely%20small%20quantity&f=false) .

Anyone can explain why the relationship between $f(x)$ and $dx$ in $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is multiplication? what does $dx$ mean here ?

Comment: So first of all, what exactly do you mean when say that the relationship between $f(x)$ and $\mathrm{d}x$ is multiplication? As for your question, I suggest to study the proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus. Also it might help to study an analysis course which covers integral without the notation $\mathrm{d}x$, which only seems to cause problems and misunderstandings.

Comment: That book in the link is not the one-stop definitive source on what's right and what's wrong in mathematics.  There is nothing wrong with infinitesimal quantities.  Also is that image with (31) even from the same book or author(s)?  If not, then you're trying to reconcile something from one book using the rationale contained in a different book or put forth by a different person.  Not always a fruitful endeavor.

Comment: @tilper yes, from the same author ,just another book here https://books.google.ca/books?id=vOMlBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA119&dq=introduction%20to%20calculus%20and%20analysis&hl=zh-CN&pg=PA190#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Mathematician42 never saw an analysis course or calculus without $dx$ or $dy$, could you give an example ?

Comment: Any measure theory book/course.

Comment: @iMath, also, note that the book you linked to in the comments is from 1989 and appears to be a reprint of a book first published in 1965.  The "$dF(x)$" notation is a little outdated, at least as far as I know.

Comment: @tilper thanks for your sustained attention on this question, but why $dF(x)$ outdated?

Comment: I've not seen that notation in any modern texts that I can recall.  Could also be a cultural thing though.

Comment: @iMath where did you get the idea that infinitesimals have no place in modern mathematics?

Answer (score 1):

Your query could be better understood in geometrical manner as follow:

In the integral

$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\, dx$

The product $f(x)\,dx $ is nothing but multiplication of height and breadth which would actually constitute area of elementary strip below curve $f(x)$ and combination of areas of these strips from $a$ to $b$ constitute total area under $f(x)$ .

Answer (score 0):

It's not really multiplication.  It's actually largely just notational.

$dx$ can be interpreted as the differential of $x$.

$dF(x)$ can be interpreted as the differential of $F(x)$, which is actually just $F'(x)\, dx.$  This comes from the fact that $\dfrac{dF(x)}{dx} = F'(x).$  We can move the $dx$ to the other side of the equation to get $dF(x) = F'(x) \, dx.$  This is known as separating the variables.  This looks like we're multiplying both sides by $dx$ but we're not.  We can't multiply by $dx$ because $dx$ doesn't actually represent a number.  It represents an infinitely small quantity, somewhat similar to how $\infty$ represents an infinitely large one.

So, when we simplify $\dfrac{dF(x)}{dx} \, dx$ to just $dF(x)$ it's just a matter of convenient notation.

Here's a concrete example following the same pattern as (31) in the provided image, where in this example I use $F(x) = \sin x.$  So then $F'(x) = \cos x$ and we have:

$$\sin 2 - \sin 1 = \int_1^2 \cos x \, dx = \int_1^2 \frac{d \sin x}{dx} \, dx = \int_1^2 d\sin x$$

Comment: If you think dx as an infinitely small quantity to explain this question , I recommend you to read this before you answer this question https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=_kYBqLc5QoQC&pg=PA404&lpg=PA404&dq=is+replaced+by+the+infinitely+small+quantity&source=bl&ots=qPT0BODYtK&sig=JdspseUMZCWouacpWgSpPtsJ0IU&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia8LTAzKbMAhVBQpQKHRjSDTkQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=is%20replaced%20by%20the%20infinitely%20small%20quantity&f=false

Comment: @iMath If you have also read what you recommend, then you should "be careful not to attach too much significance to what is, after all, a pure convention as to how the limit shall be denoted".

Comment: yes, I did read it, but in calculation,  the relationship between f(x) and dx in $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is treated as if it is multiplication, I just wonder why

Comment: @iMath, I opened the link before answering but decided it was pointless to guess exactly which parts of that you thought were relevant to the question, especially since I couldn't find anything relevant.  My answer is more than "dx is an infinitely small quantity, the end."  If my post doesn't help answer your question then please ask specific follow-up questions on what isn't clear to you rather than giving reading recommendations.

Comment: @iMath, I explained why.  It's notational convenience.

Comment: @tilper (1)you mean simplifying $\dfrac{dF(x)}{dx} \, dx$ to $dF(x)$ is just a convention ? (2) I don't think infinitesimal quantities have a legal place in the traditional (ε, δ)-definition based Calculus.

Comment: Essentially, and one that happens to work out nicely with the notation.  Surely you're familiar with the chain rule?  It's a similar situation.  If $f$ is a function of $g$ and $g$ is a function of $x$ then $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{dg} \cdot \frac{dg}{dx}$.  Notationally it looks like the $dg$ are "canceling" but that's not actually what's happening at all.  I disagree about infinitesimals not having a place.  Epsilons and deltas basically represent infinitesimals..

Comment: @iMath, what makes you feel that infinitesimals don't have a legal place? Which law have they violated?

Comment: @MikhailKatz  I think we discuss the traditional (ε, δ)-definition based Calculus in the field of extended real numbers, so there is no infinitesimals in it. MathWorld defines an infinitesimal as some quantity that is explicitly nonzero and yet smaller in absolute value than any real quantity, However , a quantity which is smaller in absolute value than any real quantity is obviously zero, if still require the quantity to be nonzero, then no such quantity exists in real number systerm.

Comment: That doesn't mean infinitesimals have no legitimate place in math.  On the contrary, it's precisely that definition that gives them a legitimate place.  One can make that same argument on the other extreme about infinity.  $\infty$ represents a quantity whose size is larger than any finite number.  Clearly no such real number exists, but $\infty$ certainly has a legit place in math.

Comment: @MikhailKatz In a later revised edition of the book, the book finally acknowledge that infinitesimal are respectable in mathematics https://books.google.com/books?id=UfdossHPlkgC&pg=PA293-IA56&lpg=PA293-IA56&dq=On+page+435+Courant+and+Robbins+remark+that+%22+%27differentials%27+as+in-+infinitely+small+quantities&source=bl&ots=Wrt62YYwda&sig=DROp1WFekS8M5MXjfRf4noKBgdY&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4s--f3LvMAhXMKJQKHSsrBEcQ6AEIHTAA

Comment: iMath, that's great, thanks! @AsafKaragila

Comment: @iMath, if you want to know why and in what sense $f(x)dx$ is a product, you need to either do infinitesimals or do differential forms. In other words, to get an answer to your original question, you are going to have to learn *something* new :-)

Comment: @MikhailKatz   Finally, I convinced of myself that  $f(x)dx$  is a product by thinking it originates from $dF(x)=f(x)△x =f(x)dx$ as described here https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=vOMlBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA179&dq=we%20%20shall%20call%20the%20differential%20%20dy%20%20of%20%20y%20%20and%20write%20for%20it&hl=zh-CN&pg=PA180#v=onepage&q=we%20%20shall%20call%20the%20differential%20%20dy%20%20of%20%20y%20%20and%20write%20for%20it&f=false  ,but do not think it as the multiplication of height and width of an infinitesimal rectangle in the traditional (ε, δ)-definition based Calculus.

Comment: @MikhailKatz and the relationship between $dF(x)=f(x)△x =f(x)dx$ and $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\, dx$  is the Fundamental Theorems of Calculus $ \int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b F'(x)\,dx =\int_a^b dF(x)= F(b) - F(a). $

Comment: @MikhailKatz what do you mean by "do differential forms" ? In what sense it relates to the original question?

Comment: @iMath one way of interpreting $\int f(x)dx$ is in terms of integration of differential forms.  Here $dx$ is a differential 1-form.  Differential 1-forms can be multiplied by functions.  Thus $f(x)dx$ is another differential 1-form.  I can provide references if you are interested. But I believe the approach with infinitesimals is more intuitive and more consistent with Leibniz's original vision.

Comment: @iMath, I am  not sure I follow your comment that "I convinced of myself that f(x)dx  is a product by thinking it originates from dF(x)=f(x)△x=f(x) as described in the book but do not think it as the multiplication of height and width of an infinitesimal rectangle in the traditional (ε, δ)-definition based Calculus". If by "traditional" you mean "respectable" (in that it avoids infinitesimals) then this is correct. Otherwise keep in mind that epsilon-delta and infinitesimals happily coexist in Keisler's book at the link I provided in my answer.

Comment: @MikhailKatz The traditional (ε, δ)-definition based Calculus avoid infinitesimals and deny the existence of it.

Comment: @iMath, you seem to have had a relapse.  You already mentioned above that Courant repented in a later edition and declared infinitesimals to be consistent. Some calculus courses avoid infinitesimals, others use both infinitesimals and epsilon-delta, but nobody nowadays follows Bishop Berkeley in claiming that they are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

In [Keisler's calculus book](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html) it is explained how the expression $f(x)dx$ can indeed be viewed as a product.  The dismissive comment about infinitesimals that you quote seem to come from the book by Courant and Robbins.  This was written before Abraham Robinson introduced modern infinitesimals in 1961.  Some of Galois' contemporaries also laughed at him when he introduced group theory.